# Question regarding to the type in C++ template of _deque_iterator

Tags: c++, templates, types, type-definition

I am studying the code of Deque Itereator.

```
template <class T, class Ref, class Ptr, size_t BufSiz>
class _deque_iterator
{
    typedef _deque_iterator<T, T&, T*, BufSiz> iterator; 
    typedef _deque_iterator<T, const T&, const T*, BufSiz> const_iterator; 
    static size_t buffer_size() { return _deque_buf_size(BufSiz, sizeof(T)); }

    typedef random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category; 
    typedef T value_type; 
    typedef Ptr pointer; 
    typedef Ref reference;
    typedef size_t size_type; 
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type; 
    typedef T** map_pointer; 

    typedef _deque_iterator self; 

    T* cur; 
    T* first; 
    T* last; 

    map_pointer node;
....
}
```

I am wondering if it make any difference if I replace `T*` with `Ptr`, as in:

```
Ptr cur; 
Ptr first; 
Ptr last;
```

Similarly another question, the member `map` is used to store an arrary of Ptr pointing to the buffer area, can I also change the type like:

```
//typedef T** map_pointer;
typedef Ptr* map_pointer;
```

Would it lead to any inconvenience when using this template? or these 2 ways are just equal? Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Why do you think `Ptr` is `T*`? Look at `const_iterator`, `Ptr` can be `const T*`.

Comment: @273K thanks for your reply but I did not get your point.  Just like you mentioned if I want to use  const_iterator, Ptr indeed can be const T*. But I suppose thats exactly what I want? Because I am defining a const_iterator which means I am not planing  to mofify the data set by this iterator.  It sounds like a const T* cur point would just meet my requirments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it lead to any inconvenience when using this template?

It would (probably) cease to work for `const_iterator`, because you have changed from `T *` data members to `const T *`. Especially `map_pointer`, where there isn't an implicit conversion from `T **` to `const T **`.